# How to separate duplicate and unique values using a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, duplicates

I'm trying to find a way to separate duplicates and unique numbers from a list. I was told to explore using a dictionary. I can put the values into a dictionary to eradicate the duplicates but I'm a little lost from there.

Also I can never get the output exactly the same (it looks like a loop).

Input:

```
2
16
25
2
49
75
49
49
```

Output:

```
Non-duplicates:
16
25
75

Duplicates:
2
49
```

```
# duplicate_values = []
# unique_values = []

for x in lst:
    if lst.count(x) == 1:
        unique_values.append(x)
    elif x not in duplicate_values:
        duplicate_values.append(x)
```

Comment: You could use a dictionary to record how often each value occurs.

Comment: What is the problem with the code example?  It seems to work just fine (after uncommenting the list declarations, and renaming `duplicate` to `duplicate_values`).

Comment: Thanks @JohnGordon. the feedback i got from my instructor is "this may work, but explore the use of a dictionary here." 

The topic was on data stuctures.....also I think the output has to match exaclty

Comment: _I can put the values into a dictionary to eradicate the duplicates but I'm a little lost from there_ You probably overlooked the step where if a number is already in the dictionary, you're supposed to add 1 to its value.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty dictionary.

Iterate over each number in the input list.

If that number does not exist in the dictionary, add it with a value of 1.  Otherwise if it does exist already, add 1 to its value.

The unique numbers will be those with a value of exactly 1 in the dictionary.  All the other numbers are duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way you are using to remove duplicates is the 'set()' method

Your code has incorrect logic, you are counting the values and comparing if it is equal to 1, but as there is more than one value it is going to the next step, your else, in this it is not adding the values that are duplicated.

```py
list_input = [2,16,25,2,49,75,49,49]

unique_values = []

for x in list_input:
    if x not in unique_values:
        unique_values.append(x)
print(unique_values)
```

output:

```
[16, 25, 75, 2, 49]
```

Solution:

```py
list_input = [2,16,25,2,49,75,49,49]


your_dict = {
    'unique': [],
    'duplicate': [],
}

for x in list_input:
    if x not in your_dict['unique']:
        your_dict['unique'].append(x) 
    else:
        your_dict['duplicate'].append(x) 

print(your_dict)
```

output

```
{'unique': [2, 16, 25, 49, 75], 'duplicate': [2, 49, 49]}
```

[Example set](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp)

Zero duplicates in list:

```py
list_input = [2,16,25,2,49,75,49,49]

use_set = list(set(list_input))

print(use_set)
```

output

```
[2, 75, 16, 49, 25]
```

Zero duplicates to dict:

```py
to_dict = {}

for x, y in enumerate(use_set):
    to_dict[x] = y
    
print(to_dict)
```

output

```
{0: 2, 1: 75, 2: 16, 3: 49, 4: 25}
```